# Unable to download scripts in VUgen after connecting to HP PC

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am receiving an error while downloading the scripts from PC to VuGen. I have logged into the respective project in PC and able to see the scripts but I'm unable to download.

This is the error I'm receiving while I try to download the scripts:

> Downloading is not permitted
>
> Could not load script. No script was found in folder

Also the download option in PC is disabled.

Comment: Could be that you don't have permission to the temp directory. Try loading a script from zip (from a local hard drive) and see if the error persists.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: In my universe, "urgent" equates to willing to pay for an answer